# Fragment ViewOnClickListener

Tags: android

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);


    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);

    if (!UtilChat.checkConnection(getActivity())){
        UtilChat.initToast(getActivity(), "LOL");

       // finish();
    }else{
        bindViews();
        verificaUsuarioLogado();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();
    }

    return view;
}

private void bindViews(){
    contentRoot = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contentRoot);
    edMessage = (EmojiconEditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    btSendMessage = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonMessage);
    btSendMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
    btEmoji = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonEmoji);
    emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(getActivity(),contentRoot,edMessage,btEmoji);
    emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
    rvListMessage = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
}
```

Ошибка:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: sky.alien.korenovskguide.MainActivity
>   cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
>                                                                                 at
>   sky.alien.korenovskguide.ChatActivity.bindViews(ChatActivity.java:141)
>                                                                                 at
>   sky.alien.korenovskguide.ChatActivity.onCreateView(ChatActivity.java:126)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2191)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1164)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Строка:

```
  btSendMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
```

И вторая:

```
 }else{
        bindViews();
        verificaUsuarioLogado();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Alt+Enter на подчеркивание красным и Make ... imlement

Comment: @ЮрийСПб btSendMessage.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());  Вот так получилось

Comment: @ЮрийСПб implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, ClickListenerChatFirebase